# Is there any way to deploy PHP forms on my Google Drive hosted website?

Tags: php, html, google-drive-api

I am using my google drive space to host my website (I followed the instructions here in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtQ9TvQLKjc&t=291s) and it is all functional and working except the PHP forms in my HTML website template!

When I contacted BootstrapeMade.com where I purchased my website template from, they told me that the reason is that my hosting does not provide PHP support.

I searched online but I couldn't find anything useful and google drive API documentation is overwelmingly poor written. So I was wondering if there is anybody here who can help me answering this questions for me: What is the best way to use PHP forms on my Google Drive hosted website? Is it even possible? If yes, how exactly?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not execute any PHP code on google drive. PHP is a backend development language and you need a server to execute it. Google Drive works like storage, and you can only share your HTML, CSS, JS files publicly on it.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
I just want to point the most popular one.
I will Edit it. 
thanks.